# How do I create a pause or delay when hovering over javascript list items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

hoping someone can help.

I'm a javascript novice.  I have a list of names that, when hovered over, display a box with that person's contact information.

The problem I'm having is that the box displays too fast; causing boxes to fire off rapidly when mousing over multiple names.

Link: http://law.nd.edu/faculty/

Here's what I believe is the relevant code:

```
<script>
jQuery(".directory-list li").hover(
function() {
  jQuery(this).find(".directory-info").fadeIn(200); ;
},
function() {
  jQuery(this).find(".directory-info").fadeOut(50);;
}
);
</script>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The box is doing exactly what your `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` numbers suggest.  Have you tried increasing those numbers?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I believe OP wants some delay before the fadeIn starts, not elongate the fadeIn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle, think this is what you want. The other answer that uses timeoutes will loose the context of `this` inside the `setTimeout()` function and will not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/RZUVS/1/.

Comment: @techfoobar - I would have commented on your answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet. :)

Comment: Also, it is regular practice in SO to include the relevant code from your answer here itself (so it helps reader faster).

Comment: Thanks all; I was able to work with this code. Glad for the support; used this site many times - first time I've needed to ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

Use hoverIntent instead.

There is a nice little plugin for it, that is the easiest way to do it.

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

It will keep your elements from rapid-firing.

Answer (score 2):

You can *introduce* a delay by using setTimeout as follows:

```
var hoverTimer;
jQuery(".directory-list li").hover(function() {
  var elem = jQuery(this).find(".directory-info");
  hoverTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    elem.fadeIn(200);
  }, 1000); // wait for one second and then fadeIn
},
function() {
  clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
  jQuery(this).find(".directory-info").fadeOut(50);
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the un-hover callback cancel the timeout, so it doesn't display the pop-up if the mouse moves out?

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, it should. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: Looks like the `hoverIntent` plugin in dsundy's answer addresses this in a neat package.

Comment: I guess you meant Tabetha Moe's answer instead.

Comment: Wish it was my answer... I'm feeling guilty about my two votes.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to add a delay before your fadeIn:

```
jQuery(this).find(".directory-info").delay(300).fadeIn(200);
```

Comment: This will still display all the pop-ups in rapid-fire, just 300 ms later than before.

Comment: Also not sure if doing it this way will make it un-cancelable (on mouseout)

Comment: True. hoverIntent is probably the way to go. I'm giving that an upvote.